# Payment method token is invalid in Braintree

Tags: python, token, payment-gateway, braintree

I want to test it on the side of the functionality of the subscription payment gateway Braintree - for my application using Django (python).

Your code I have only one py file. (without front-end). When I want to create a subscription I get an error:

```
<ErrorResult 'Payment method token is invalid.' at 7f101d301390>
```

How can I get token payment method?

Here is all my code:

```
import braintree

braintree.Configuration.configure(braintree.Environment.Sandbox,
                                  merchant_id="myMechrantId",
                                  public_key="myPublicKey",
                                  private_key="myPrivateKey")

client_token = braintree.ClientToken.generate()

client = braintree.Customer.create({
    "first_name": 'Mike',
    "last_name": "Smith",
    "company": "Braintree",
    "email": "jen@example.com",
    "phone": "312.555.1234",
    "fax": "614.555.5678",
    "website": "www.example.com"
})

result = braintree.Subscription.create({
    "payment_method_token": "the_token",
    "plan_id": "Here is my plan ID"
})
```

Answer (score 7):

<sub>I work at Braintree. Please [get in touch with our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/) if you have more questions.</sub>

In general, one of the main benefits of a service like Braintree is that you never have to handle credit card numbers, so you're better off [following the Braintree recurring billing guide](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+python/guides/recurring-billing) instead, which will better match a real integration with Braintree.

That said, if you do want to test it without a front-end, you can test it like this:

```
result = braintree.Customer.create({
    "credit_card": {
        "number": "4111111111111111",
        "expiration_date": "12/16"
    }
})

result = braintree.Subscription.create({
    "payment_method_token": result.customer.credit_cards[0].token,
    "plan_id": "my_plan_id"
})
```

Comment: @AwaisMustafa Yes, create the subscription with the payment method token for the PayPal account.

Comment: @agf Can you please tell me how we can get token frim paypal acc ?

Comment: @SachinShah Please reach out to Braintree support with your question, but it's basically the same except replace the `credit_cards` bit.

Comment: It took me forever to find something which made sense for the value of payment_method_toke. Why can't they just call it payment_method_id

Comment: @BogdanM. In general, the distinction is that `_token`s can be set by the merchant via the API while `_id`s can't be.

Comment: oh, touche. Thanks it does make sense now :)

Answer (score 0):

It's late but I got stuck on this problem recently, this is the solution that helped me

```
customer_create_result = gateway.customer.create({
        "first_name": user.first_name,
        "last_name": user.middle_name + '' + user.last_name,
        "payment_method_nonce": payment_method_nonce
    })
subscription_create_result = gateway.subscription.create({
        "payment_method_token":
        customer_create_result.customer.payment_methods[0].token,
        "plan_id": braintree_plan_id
    })
```

where **payment_method_nonce** can be obtained from **payload.nonce** on payment button click and **braintree_plan_id** is the id for the plan you create in braintree control panel

here is the braintree reference that helped me
https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/docs/guides/customers#create-with-payment-method